# Redux reducers for nested redux store properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I want to shape my redux store like this and add more siblings of searchForm:

```
import { Map } from 'immutable'

const searchForm = Map(
  {
    'categories': ['meat'],
    'mealTypes': [],
    'location': {
      place: {},
      distanceFromPlaceValue: 10,
      distanceFromPlaceUnit: 'k'
    },
    'keywords': ''
  }
)

const initialState = Map(
  {
    searchForm: searchForm
  }
)

export default initialState
```

So far I have made reducers for `categories` and `keywords` of the searchForm and are creating the store like this:

```
const reducer = combineReducers({ keywords, categories })
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  devToolsEnhancer()
)
```

That gives an error:

> unexpected property "searchForm" found in previous state by the
>   reducer...

`CreateStore` needs to take reducers that match the top level properties of the redux store. Is there are way to nest the store how I have done and pass in the reducers without error? Or will I need to change the shape of my redux store and have any reducers be top level store properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Redux initial state doc :

> If you produced reducer with combineReducers, this must be a plain
>   object with the same shape as the keys passed to it. Otherwise, you
>   are free to pass anything that your reducer can understand.

You use combineReducer with `keyword` and `categories` keys so your initial state also have to include such keys but in your case it includes only `searchForm` key.

You don't need to change shape of your state, you can simply use nested `combineRedcuers`:

```
const reducer = combineReducers({searchForm: combineReducers({ keywords, categories })});
```

Please note that if you use Redux `combineReducers`, state object managed by this reducer has to be plain object (not Immutable object). 
So I'd suggest something like this:

```
const searchForm = {
    'categories': List(..),
    'mealTypes': List(...),
    'location': Map(...),
    'keywords': ''
}

const initialState =   {
    searchForm: searchForm
};
```

If you want to use Immutable object as initial state you can use [Redux-Immutable](https://github.com/gajus/redux-immutable) which provides `combineReducers` method that uses Immutable.js API to iterate the state. Please check this [discussion](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1100) for more details.

Besides, no matter whether you use Redux or Redux-Imuable state object (plain or Immutable) properties must correspond to keys of object passed to `combineReducers`.

Comment: Thanks this works. I just realised I'm already using `import { combineReducers } from 'redux-immutable'`